# javascript - Bookmarklet for modifying the start of an URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My university allows us to access journal articles through the library search engine, which is a hassle to use. All it does is modify the URL of a given resource as follows:

From

```
https://(www.)database.com/article-link
```

To

```
https://0-(www.)database.com.elibrary.qatar-weill.cornell.edu/article-link
```

Now, I'm looking to make a bookmarklet which prefixes the **0-** part to the URL and adds in the **.elibrary.qatar-weill.cornell.edu** part at the end. As of yet, I've got the second part working by putting the following code into the bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){var l=location;l.href=l.origin+l.href.replace(l.origin,'.elibrary.qatar-weill.cornell.edu');})();
```

But I can't find a way to add **0-** to the start of an URL without everything breaking. Any ideas?

Comment: replace `https://` by `https://0-` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding an additional `replace` method call which affects the `l.origin` of the URL?

```
javascript:(function(){var l=location;l.href=l.origin.replace("//", "//0-")+l.href.replace(l.origin,'.elibrary.qatar-weill.cornell.edu');})();
```

This seeks out `//` inside the URL's origin (the `https://database.com` part) and replaces it with `//0-`.

Comment: Excellent, that's working like a charm. I kept trying to add the second modifier into the existing replace function rather than just adding a new one.